# Magento: ImageCdn bug? (long story)

Tags: magento

I have some question related with Magento's free extension [OnePica ImageCdn](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/onepica-imagecdn.html).

A broken image appear in frontend when I uploaded "corrupt image".
[image]

Ok, let's start the long story:

I notice it is happened because of ImageCdn extension and "corrupt image".

In some part of ImageCdn's code:

```
OnePica_ImageCdn_Helper_Image

/**
 * In older versions of Magento (<1.1.3) this method was used to get an image URL.
 * However, 1.1.3 now uses the getUrl() method in the product > image model. This code
 * was added for backwards compatibility.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    parent::__toString();
    return $this->_getModel()->getUrl();
}
```

My question is, anybody know what is the purpose of that code?
I don't understand what is the meaning of their comment above.
I think it is a bug as it always `return $this->_getModel()->getUrl();`

Is is really a bug or it is just my wrong interpretation?

This is what I've done so far:

- I have an image `dummy.jpeg`
- After some investigation, I just realized that is a "corrupt image".
- I tested using: `<?php print_r(getimagesize('dummy.jpeg')); ?>`

Result:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => 200
>     [1] => 200
>     [2] => 6
>     [3] => width="200" height="200"
>     [bits] => 24
>     [mime] => image/x-ms-bmp
> )
> ```

Of course I was surprised by the result because it looks good when I open it using `Preview` (on Mac OSX)
[image: looks good]

- Then I open it using hex editor, the first two bytes is : `BM` which is BMP's identifier
- I tried to upload .bmp image for product -> failed, can not select the image
- I asked my colleague to upload it too (on Ubuntu), he was able to change the choices for file type into "any files". When he click "Upload Files", error message shown state that that type of file is not allowed.
- What crossed on my mind is: an admin tried to upload `.bmp` image and failed. Then he rename it into `.jpeg` and successful. Though I don't get it what kind of images can be renamed without showing broken image logo (out of topic).
- Those scenarios trigger an Exception, I'll break down what I've traced.

Trace of the codes:

> - app/design/frontend/base/default/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

```
<?php
    $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
?>
```

- From that code, I know that image url is generated using: `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')`
- I did `Mage::log((string)$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'));`

> Result:
>   `http://local.m.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/d/u/dummy.jpeg`

.

> - Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image

```
public function __toString()
{
    try {
        if( $this->getImageFile() ) {
            $this->_getModel()->setBaseFile( $this->getImageFile() );
        } else {
            $this->_getModel()->setBaseFile( $this->getProduct()->getData($this->_getModel()->getDestinationSubdir()) );
        }

        if( $this->_getModel()->isCached() ) {
            return $this->_getModel()->getUrl();
        } else {
            if( $this->_scheduleRotate ) {
                $this->_getModel()->rotate( $this->getAngle() );
            }

            if ($this->_scheduleResize) {
                $this->_getModel()->resize();
            }

            if( $this->getWatermark() ) {
                $this->_getModel()->setWatermark($this->getWatermark());
            }
Mage::log('pass');
            $url = $this->_getModel()->saveFile()->getUrl();
Mage::log('not pass');
        }
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        $url = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($this->getPlaceholder());
    }
    return $url;
}
```

- The error triggered in `$this->_getModel()->saveFile()->getUrl()`. In some part of the code, it will eventually reach:

> Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2

```
private function _getCallback($callbackType, $fileType = null, $unsupportedText = 'Unsupported image format.')
{
    if (null === $fileType) {
        $fileType = $this->_fileType;
    }
    if (empty(self::$_callbacks[$fileType])) {
        //reach this line -> exception thrown
        throw new Exception($unsupportedText);
    }
    if (empty(self::$_callbacks[$fileType][$callbackType])) {
        throw new Exception('Callback not found.');
    }
    return self::$_callbacks[$fileType][$callbackType];
}
```

> - The exception was catched in the previous code:

```
Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image
public function __toString()
{
    ...
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        $url = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($this->getPlaceholder());
    }
    ...
}
```

> the $url became:
>   `http://local.m.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg`

- So, it should have generated placeholder image right?
  [image: placeholder]
  (without ImageCdn extension)
- No, because

> `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` was rewritten by
>   `OnePica_ImageCdn_Helper_Image`

```
public function __toString()
{
    parent::__toString(); //the result is http://local.m.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg but no variable store/process its value
    return $this->_getModel()->getUrl(); //in the end it will return http://local.m.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/d/u/dummy.jpeg
}
```

In case you all already forgot the question:
Anybody know what is the purpose of that code? I don't understand what is the meaning of their comment above.
Is it really a bug or it is just my wrong interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't a bug. It's just legacy support for older Magento systems. I'm wondering, have you ever got around to snoop around earlier versions of magento (as the inline documentation comment references to, < 1.1.3)?

The gist of the matter is before Mage 1.1.3, `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` instances happen to produce URL's from to-string casts e.g.

```
$image = (some instance of Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image).. ;
$imageUrl = (string) $image;
```

`__toString` is probably either `protected` or `private`, i'm not sure but what I'm sure is the usual practice is to always code up this Magic Method in order to use it in a class that you are meaning to rewrite something with that expects to use this kind data cast.

Comment: The problem is, `OnePica_ImageCdn_Helper_Image` will always `return $this->_getModel()->getUrl()` even when there are exception occurred in `parent::__toString();`. When an exception occured in `__toString` function, it should generate `$url = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($this->getPlaceholder());` which didn't happen in my case because of `OnePica_ImageCdn_Helper_Image`